# How I can change the color of a themed box?

Tags: 14.04, themes

I recently installed a custom theme in my Ubuntu 14.04.02 and I need to know how (and where's and what's the .cfg and the line for change the color value) I can change the color of the 'miniatures box' in the left box of folders. I want change the dark background.

Picture of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the theme property values by editing the `nautilus.css` file. This file may be located here:

```
/usr/share/themes/$YOUR_THEME/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

Replace `$YOUR_THEME` with the name of your theme. The file requires root privileges to be edited. You can edit the file by copying and pasting the following command in a Terminal and then entering your password:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/$YOUR_THEME/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

Once again replace `$YOUR_THEME` with the name of your theme.

When you've successfully opened the file you may now look for the following lines of code. If you opened the file using Gedit you can search using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

```
...
NautilusWindow .sidebar,
NautilusWindow .sidebar .view {
...
```

This may look a bit different, maybe only one of the two lines are specified or maybe more have been added, so be patient and look carefully for something similar to the lines above.

You may now look below this code for a line with the following code:

```
...
background-color: $VALUE;
...
```

`$VALUE` can be any color value and is the background color of your right side menu. You can replace the value by any valid hexadecimal color code or rgb code (among other ways). Examples:

```
background-color: #00ff00; //Green background
background-color: rgb (255, 255, 0); //Blue background
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's work, friend! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Glad to hear :)